# Format hms vector as custom format

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to convert an `hms` vector into a `character` vector of a format like "13:15":

```
t <- hms::as_hms(ymd_hm("2021-07-23 13:15"))
```

Now formatting with something like `format(t, "%H:%M")` does not lead to the desired result.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may try regex approach to remove last 2 numbers from `t`.

```
sub(':\\d{2}$', '', t)
#[1] "13:15"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste the components:

```
t <- hms::as_hms(ymd_hm("2021-07-23 13:15"))

paste0(hour(t),":",minute(t))
```

Output:

```
[1] "13:15"
```

Comment: I am wondering why there is not any formatting function already defined.